# How can I stop an event from being triggered on a child element rather than adding pointer events none?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-delegation

How can I prevent the element within an element triggering the element within?
Is there a better way than adding pointer-events none?

```
const selectors = {
    scrollContainer: '[data-scroll-container]',
    scrollTrigger: '[data-scroll-trigger]',
    scrollNext: 'data-next',
    scrollBack: 'data-back',
};

/**
 * Main
 */

const scrollTrigger = [...document.querySelectorAll(selectors.scrollTrigger)];


const handleScroll = ({ target }) => {
    console.log(target);
    if (target.hasAttribute(data-next)) {
        console.log(target)
    }
};
```

```
<button data-scroll-trigger data-next>
       <svg>//some svg here//</svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you share how the handler is attached

Comment: @chev I've updated my question.
When I log this to the console i get the SVG (unless obvs clicking outside the svg)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to determine from the code provided and feels like there may be some design issues, but I would simply add the handler on the outermost container and then use `currentTarget` property or `target` property as needed.

The difference being `target` is the element that triggered the event and `currentTarget` is the element that has the handler attached to it. Child elements will propagate events up to parent handlers. If you want to get the parent, use `currentTarget`.

There are numerous ways to test if the element triggering is the element that the handler is attached to, but here is a very basic demo:

```js
document
  .querySelector('#outer')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget !== e.target);
    if (e.currentTarget !== e.target) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

```css
#outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<a id="outer" href="http://google.com">
  <a id="inner" />
</a>
```

Comment: Well I'm testing if the button is next or back
If it is back then i will call the next function.
But currently the svg is the "target". So i guess i want to prevent the svg from triggering the event

Comment: Updated the example to include how to prevent default actions using `preventDefault()`